# Lookup using an ID array with pipeline

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object

I was trying to write a lookup function that takes an array with object ids and timestamps of object y. This worked flawlessly with `localflied` and `foreignfield` but I cannot reproduce the same result using pipeline.

(Names like `y` are made up to keep it general)

Working version:

```
$lookup: {
   from: 'y',
   localField: 'ys.object_id',
   foreignField: '_id',
   as: 'docs',
},
```

`ys` is an array of objects structured like this:

```
{
  object_id: ObjectID(),
  timestamp: Date(),
}
```

I would like to rewrite this expression to use pipeline because I already want to filter some of the objects looked up out using their timestamp attribute.

What I have tried:

```
$lookup: {
   from: 'y',
   let: { ys: '$ys' },
   pipeline: [
     {
       $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$ys.object_id'] } },
     },
   ],
   as: 'docs',
},
```

Database size: **20.4GB**

Full Query:

```
const query = [
  {
    $match: { 'ys.timestamp': { $lte: date, $gt: previousMonth } },  // I have shorten this part a little (It's not the same but the logic was flawed anyway)
  },
  {
    $limit: 100,
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'y',
      let: { ys: '$ys' },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: { $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$ys.object_id'] } },
        },
        {
          $sort: { timestamp: -1 },
        },
        {
          $limit: 1,
        },
      ],
      as: 'doc',
    },
  },
];
```

The above solution doesn't work it seems to get stuck and never actually return anything. (Times out after some time)

Is there a proper way of rewriting the working solution to a pipeline solution?

**IMPORTANT**:
I have changed the query to look for one specific element by ID and then perform the lookup. This action did work but took about 20 seconds. I am pretty certain this is why my query times out when I run it with my usual query. Can anyone explain why there is a performance difference between the 2 approaches and if I can somehow bypass that?

Comment: use `$in` instead of `$eq`. `{
       $match: { $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$ys.object_id'] } },
     },`

Comment: See comment under Answer 1 @Fanpark

Comment: Post some more details about your collection size, server and show your full query. Most probably a single document is exceeding the BSON limit here.

Comment: If the 2 different queries are equivalent shouldn't the size of the object generate not change at all then?

Comment: Please show what we needed. Collection size, your full query.

Comment: I have added both the full query and the size of my database

Comment: Do you want to retrieve all the data at once? Don't have `$limit`? And also add this stages inside `$lookup` pipeline `{ $sort: { timestamp: -1 }},
{ $limit: 1 }`

Comment: I have tried that. It actually does get rid of the need of having the second `$addfields` expression, but I ran a timing for this query and limited the output to just 1 and it took `Time elapsed: 60.77 seconds` to execute the query which is my main issue at the moment.

Comment: Create an index on `timestamp` field. You don't have `$limit` on main pipeline?

Comment: I do set a limit on the query when executing it `const result = await collecion.aggregate(query).limit(x).toArray();` but this limit `x` varies on user input.
Setting the index actually reduced the time spent to `Time elapsed: 4.71 seconds` although when I run it on limit `x` = 100 it times out again

Comment: Use `$limit` inside the query as stage. before the `$lookup` stage.

Comment: The time for limit = 1 descresed to 1 second but the time for limit = 100 remained `Time elapsed: 87.407 seconds`

Comment: Please edit your query again.

Comment: I have updated the query

Comment: Do you have index on the timestamp field which is inside the first `$match`?

Comment: yes, such index already exists
`"note" : "all indexes already exist",`

Answer (score 0):

Very close - use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in) instead of [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq):

```
$lookup: {
   from: 'y',
   let: { ys: '$ys' },
   pipeline: [
     {
       $match: { $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$ys.object_id'] } },
     },
   ],
   as: 'docs',
},
```

If you use `$eq` you're looking for a value that is equal to that array. Using `$in` means you're looking for a value that is contained within that array (like `includes`).

Comment: This solution makes my request timeout as well. Is there a chance that using pipeline in this particular scenario takes up much more processing power and therefore times out? I am dealing with a quite large database